# Identity of dirac delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Show that

1. if f is continuous

$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\delta(x)) = f(0)\delta'(x)$

2. if f is differentiable, use Leibnitz rule to conclude that

$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\delta(x)) = f'(x)\delta(x)+f(x)\delta'(x)$

I stuck at starting the proof. Should I use integration to do both proof?

Comment: If you use the definition of the distributional derivative, the situation is pretty straightforward. For instance, $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x) \delta(x))$ should be a distribution which maps a test function $\phi$ to $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(x) f(x) \delta(x)=-\phi'(0) f(0)$ (by the definition of $\delta$).

Comment: @Ian thank you. Can you also give me hints in part 2? Thanks

Comment: You just do the calculation, as I said before. The key thing will be that in the second term, $\delta'$ acts not just on $\phi$ but on $f \phi$, so you'll need the ordinary product rule to handle that term.

Comment: @Ian but where does Leibnitz rule come in part 2? Thanks

Comment: In the second term: when you apply $\delta'$ to $f \phi$ you have to differentiate $f \phi$, which is a product, so you have to use the Leibniz product rule.